# Why GCM send Re-registration request to myserver?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

i using gcm services.some time a got a re-registration request at my server with user reg-id. it happens for some users only.the registration request came from gcm server. 
can any one explain me why this happens???

Comment: Your question is unclear. GCM server doesn't send registration IDs to your server directly (unless you are referring to canonical registration IDs). If you app registers multiple times, it could get a new registration ID for the same device.

Comment: gcm server give canonical id after sending message am i right sir ??. but my question is different  .some time Gcm server send PARAMETER_REG_ID to my server after 12 o'clock (night) on my "RegisterServlet.java" file